# C# Entidad con id Guid no me permite registrar en base de datos

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

he modificado la pregunta a raíz de sus peticiones: primeramente, aclarar que mi base de datos la he generado mediante el wizard que posee Visual Studio (2015 es el que uso) con la vía de **ADO.NET Entity Model** (ver imagen adjunta), en el cual diseñé mis entidades y luego las generé sobre la base de datos (*aquí les pido una valoración de esta vía*).

[image: Forma en que generé mi base de datos]

Las propiedades que puse en el diseño sobre la entidad son estas:

[image: Propiedades de la entidad Reloj en el diseño]

Luego de la generación del DDL, este es el código SQL de la tabla Reloj (nombrada por el EF como RelojSet)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RelojSet] (
   [Id] uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL,
   [Direccion] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
   [Puerto] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
   [Descripcion] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
   [Activo] bit  NOT NULL,
   [LastUpdate] datetime  NULL
);
GO
```

El contexto es el siguiente (no he tocado nada, esta autogenerado por EF):

```
public partial class ZKTDataBaseContainer : DbContext
{
    public ZKTDataBaseContainer()
        : base("name=ZKTDataBaseContainer")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Reloj> RelojSet { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Trabajador> TrabajadorSet { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Marcaje> MarcajeSet { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Settings> SettingsSet { get; set; }
}
```

El mapeo creado en modelo es el que les referí anteriormente:

```
public partial class Reloj
{
    public Reloj()
    {
        this.Marcaje = new HashSet<Marcaje>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Puerto { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public bool Activo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Marcaje> Marcaje { get; set; }
}
```

En mi controlador, instancio un objeto de tipo Reloj, y trato de persistirlo:

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)        
    var reloj = new Reloj
    {
        Activo = collection.Get("Activo").Equals("on"),
        Descripcion = collection.Get("Descripcion"),
        Direccion = collection.Get("Direccion"),
        Puerto = collection.Get("Puerto"),
        LastUpdate = DateTime.Now,
        Id = Guid.newGuid(),   // => No funciona
        // Id = new Guid() => No Funciona
        // Id = Guid.Parse("3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301") => Tampoco
        // Id = Guid.TryParse("3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301") => Menos
    };

    try{
        using (var db = new ZKTDataBaseContainer())
        {
            db.RelojSet.Add(reloj);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){

    }
//....
}
```

El error generado esta relacionado con el identificador Guid de la entidad Reloj:

**"No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'Id', tabla 'ZKTDB.dbo.RelojSet'. La columna no admite valores NULL. Error de INSERT.\r\nSe terminó la instrucción."**

Que estoy olvidando aqui?

Comment: intenta con     Id  = Guid.NewGuid()

Comment: Me da el mismo error. Probe parseando un string:  new Guid("3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301");  y con Guid.Parse("3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301") y ninguna de las vias de construccion

Comment: ¿y qué tal con `Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`?

Comment: @Flxtr el tipo de dato de `Id` es `Guid`, no le puedo asignar simplemente un string, traté pero me da error de sintaxis

Comment: en la respuesta veo esto Id = Guid.newGuid() pero inicia con mayúscula, fue un error de tipeo al editar la pregunta o solo intentaste de esa manera?

Comment: has intentado no setear directamente la propiedad Id? por otro lado veo que una de las propiedades de la entidad generada es StorageGeneratePattern esta en Identity, podrías probar poniéndola en none?

Comment: Siempre es mejor utilizar la creacion los Identificadores de la DB en la propia DB (por razones de concurrencia y porque asi la DB es la que gestiona su valor, imaginate el caso de crear el mismo identificador, no digo que pase pero puede pasar al crear externamente) Ya se Numerico o GUID. Justamente por este ultimo conviene utilizar [NEWSEQUENTIALID()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql) cuando es columna clave o columna que se indexara (o sera parte de un indice cluster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como recomendación el GUID lo puedes generar automaticamente desde tu base de datos utilizando la instrucción [NEWID()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql) por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RelojSet]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (NEWID()), 
    [Activo] BIT NULL,
    [Descripcion] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    [Direccion] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    [Puerto] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
    [LastUpdate] DATETIME NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

Asi ya no es necesario asignar la propiedad Id dentro de tu modelo ya que esta la genera directamente la base de datos.

Comment: Creo que esto no sería meramente válido en el contexto de EF ya que la creación de objetos de MSSQL es automática, el framework se encarga de la construcción de entidades a través de la definición de la clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias @AngelRuizC, muy certero en tu solución: agregué al DDL generado por el modelo `DEFAULT (NEWID())` y efectivamente, sin especificar la propiedad `Id` en la construcción de la entidad, se persitió correctamente. +1 y Saludos

Comment: Solo agregar que queda la interrogante ¿no puedo establecer un Guid como llave primaria a una entidad desde mi código? ¿solamente desde base de datos?

Comment: Puedes utilizar el atributo [Key] dentro de dentro la libreria de DataAnnotations (System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations) de tu propiedad para asignar la llave primaria dentro de tu modelo. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Recomendacion: Utilizar **[NEWSEQUENTIALID()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql)** en vez de **NEWID()** cuando es columna clave (primary key), por cuestiones de velocidad (temas de paginamiento de indeces y creacion * verificacion de la existencia, ya que estara ORDENADO por creacion del Id, con NEWID() son todos alteatorios) O sea es un tema mas fisico y de organiaciond de DB, igualmente sigure creando identificadores GUID

Textual de docs/ayuda:

> Cuando una columna de GUID se utiliza como identificador de fila, el uso de NEWSEQUENTIALID puede ser más rápido que el uso de la función NEWID. La razón es que la función NEWID causa actividad aleatoria y utiliza menos páginas de datos en caché. El uso de NEWSEQUENTIALID también ayuda a rellenar por completo las páginas de datos y de índices

En tu ejemplo seria la columna *Id* de la siguiente manera

```
[Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()),
```

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [NEWSEQUENTIALID (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql)